# number of select types did not match || unparseable date "Tue Jan 15 00:00:00 SGT 2013"

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, web, hql

I am having an error, I'm not sure why number of select types did not match those for insert.
I have Request entity, with 3 values. billing_cycle, start_date, & end_date.
I tried adding 0 at insert but still doesn't work.

UPDATE: My date is in String. It should be Date type. I changed SELECT to VALUES.
I got new error:
Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 15 00:00:00 SGT 2013"

My insert method

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insertRequest(Request request) {
    
     try {
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd" );
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z 
    yyyy");
    Date sdate = outputFormat.parse(request.getStart_date()) ;
    Date edate= outputFormat.parse(request.getEnd_date()) ;
    
    String sqlQuery;
    
        sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Request "
                + "(billing_cycle, start_date, end_date) VALUES ("
                +  
                + request.getBilling_cycle() +", "
                + "'"+ sdate +"', "
                + "'"+ edate+"')";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My values

```
{
    "billing_cycle":"1", 
    "start_date":"Tue Jan 15 00:00:00 SGT 2013", 
    "end_date":"Thu Feb 14 00:00:00 SGT 2013"
}
```

My entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="request")
public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="request_id")
    private int request_id;

    @Column(name="billing_cycle")
    private int billing_cycle;

    @Column(name="start_date", columnDefinition="Date")
    private String start_date;

    @Column(name="end_date", columnDefinition="Date")
    private String end_date;
```

Error:

```
Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 15 00:00:00 SGT 2013"
at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
```

Structure DB:
[image]

Comment: Please add your code and stack trace as a text.

Comment: I updated it, do check

Comment: The `createQuery` method is used to create `JPQL` queries and I think it does not support the `INSERT` statement. Also why you need to use an `INSERT` statement when you have the `Request` object already available. Can try using  `entityManager.persist(request)`

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of your request_id attribut, I see that you choosed the GENERATION.AUTO strategy. So, in your insert request you should make it null.

And on the other hand, I don't understand the interest of the entity if you are going to work with simple sql queries.
You can persist your object like that :

```
entityManager.persist(request);
```

In your DB schema you are used DATE. Here you will find the difference between DATE and DATETIME

**DATE**: It is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in YYYY-MM-DD format. The supported range is 1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31.

**DATETIME**: It is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. The supported range is 1000-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.

Comment: Its still not working:
number of select types did not match those for insert [INSERT INTO Request (request_id, billing_cycle, start_date, end_date) select (null, 1, '2013-01-15', '2013-02-14')

Comment: Normally, a select in insert request should be with a table like that :
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL1, COL2, COL3) SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE2;
In your case, you should change SELECT with VALUES

Comment: Thanks. I updated it into VALUES, but I got new error.

Comment: Make your attributs to java.sql.Date that will fixe the problem

Comment: Can you give us the table structure in the DB ?

Comment: I updated it. `java.sql.Date` doesnt work on `outputFormat.parse(request.getStart_date()) ;`

Comment: You have a probleme on the parse. You need to add the Locale.US to your parser, it will be like that :

DateFormat outputFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);

DateFormat have many disadvantage, I suggest you work with the Date API of java version 8